# perl sort ip with there range of submarks

Tags: perl

I have a file name ip.txt where list of IPs i want to classify those ip with their range like

```
10.0.0.1/25
192.168.1.1/24
```

is it possible do this without adding any module Please help me out

Comment: care to elaborate how output should look like?

Answer (score 0):

Without further information it cannot be deduced that your 10.0.0.1 belongs to a /25 network.

Comment: What if we use http://routeviews.org/bgpdata/2001.10/RIBS/ to fetch ips subnet Net:Patricia

BGPDUMP tool with perl
any idea about this